# ora-00904 invalid identifier on creating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I am having issues with creating a view , the sql query tests successfully from the create view pane as seen on the right pane

[image]

Oracle is throwing me an invalid identifier , but oracle does not point to which part of the query

[image]

Comment: Why don't you remove the stuff nested within brackets following VIEWB --> `(SELECTCAPACIT.....='FBN001'))`, and alias each column within the SELECT list ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example can be simplified to:

```sql
CREATE VIEW test AS
  SELECT (SELECT 2 FROM DUAL) - (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
  FROM DUAL;
```

Which fails as Oracle does not know what to call the column the view generates and SQL Developer is trying to automatically generate the SQL by copying the default alias into the signature:

```sql
CREATE VIEW test( (SELECT2FROMDUAL)-(SELECT1FROMDUAL) ) AS
  SELECT (SELECT 2 FROM DUAL) - (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
  FROM DUAL;
```

Which is an invalid identifier.

Either set the identifier for the column in the query:

```sql
CREATE VIEW test AS
  SELECT (SELECT 2 FROM DUAL) - (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL) AS value
  FROM DUAL;
```

or in the signature:

```sql
CREATE VIEW test(value) AS
  SELECT (SELECT 2 FROM DUAL) - (SELECT 1 FROM DUAL)
  FROM DUAL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aubnK21m)

Comment: This is an another problem with different error - ORA-00998. Invalid identifier (ORA-00904) , I think, does not mean missing identifier. Regards...

Comment: @dr This is correct; try running the second query in the answer (which is what SQL Developer will try to automatically generate as the OP is not manually supplying an identifier) and it will raise the exception `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier` (exactly as the OP's code does).

Comment: You are right. My mistake, sorry. I checked just the first one. Regards... (... and upvote)

Comment: @MT0 thanks for the kind explanation , you are right , i was really confused when the identifier error did not specify any of the columns in my original query !

i might have thought it was an issues from using the dual command , turns out it was due to me not specifying an identifier for it.